# Making all PHP-mongoDB connections use Unix domain sockets

Tags: php, mongodb, sockets

Since we started using mongoDB a while back, a large part of our PHP codebase looks like this:

```
$mongo = new Mongo();
$coll = $mongo->mydb->mycoll;
```

The default is to connect via TCP to `localhost:27017` which has worked just fine for us for a few years now. Due to speed considerations, I would like to switch to using Unix domain sockets which are supported like this:

```
$client = new MongoClient("mongodb:///tmp/mongodb-27017.sock");
```

Is there a way to make this work without having to specify the socket file in the code? The [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.configuration.php#ini.mongo.default-host) list `mongo.default_host` and `mongo.default_port` which can be set in `php.ini` so you can write:

```
$client = new MongoClient();
```

but that seems to be possible only for TCP connections. Or can I use these parameters to specify a socket file? If so, how?

Comment: I am not convinced that Unix domain sockets are faster. The driver maintains a connection pool. After the initial connection, there is little to no overhead. The bottleneck usually is RAM or the queries itself, so it is a Very Bad Idea™ to run your application (especially a PHP one) on the same machine as the MongoDB instance. They will compete for RAM. MongoDB needs a lot of RAM and each request and connection will need additional RAM. So MongoDB answers will take longer when short on RAM, queuing other operations. The longer the answers take, the more requests will queue. A vicious circle.

Comment: The speed assumption is based on the comments posted [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php#113430) and on a general observation that Unix domain sockets are very efficient compared to TCP connections. In our case, the DB is not running on the web server, only `mongos` is, so I'm not worried about competing for RAM. I simply don't want to lose resources to the overhead that TCP incurs.

Comment: @Olivier: as written, a connection pool is maintained by the driver, which leverages TCP overhead after the initial connection is made - no handshake per request and alike.